# autocomplete is not getting disabled for select element

Tags: html, reactjs, browser

I tried making autocomplete property to false , none ,off or random string as suggested by some post,

None of the mentioned are working, Do anyone know how can we disable autofill of browser for select element.

```
  componentDidMount () {
  //controlNode is select element.

  if(this.props.autoFill === false){
    this.controlNode.setAttribute('autocomplete','none');
  }

  let selectedIndex = -1;
  if (this.controlNode) {
      selectedIndex = this.controlNode.selectedIndex;
  }

  if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
      const inputDOM = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.controlNode);

      let tempOption;
      if (inputDOM.childNodes.length === 1) {
          tempOption = document.createElement('option');
          inputDOM.appendChild(tempOption);
      }

      const options = this.controlNode.options;
      const tempIndex = (selectedIndex + 1) % options.length;
      options[tempIndex].selected = true;
      options[selectedIndex].selected = true;

      if (tempOption) {
          inputDOM.removeChild(tempOption);
      }
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show your code so that contributors can find where you are facing difficulty...

Answer (score 0):

Changed `autocomplete="disabled"` for select box and it seems to be working fine , don't know why this is accepted by chrome browser.

Thanks.